# How do I select all options with jQuery with a specific value and change the value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, select

I want to select all the select elements that have a value of "-1" and change the value to blank aka "".

I want to change all these:

```
<option value="-1">Select Something</option>
```

to this:

```
<option value="">Select Year</option>
```

I am using this code:

```
jQuery().ready(function() {
    $("option[value='-1']").val('');
});
```

... which isn't working. Any idea why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery how to select options by values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031413/jquery-how-to-select-options-by-values) and [Altering the value of an option (select) element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801068/altering-the-value-of-an-option-select-element)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select options with a specific value like this:

```
$("option[value='-1']")
```

and then set a new value with the `val` function:

```
$("option[value='-1']").val('');
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/t3ncq/)

Comment: That's what I thought! But it's not working. Any ideas what I'm having problems with this?

Comment: @Dave - not sure - check out the demo I just posted

Comment: @Dave: How can we have an idea if we don't even know your code?

Comment: Moved it inside a function and it started working, not sure why it wasn't working when doing $.read()

Comment: @Dave since it was outside any function it's possible the code was getting run before the dom was ready.